# How to enable user requesting permission through email approval

Tags: permissions

We have a sharepoint environment , now we want to enable user requesting permission through email approval. That means if a user has no permission on a document, he or she can send an email to the administrator, after the administrator approval the email, the user can have the permission on this document.

How can we do this in sharepoint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has a feature called "Manage Access Requests," which can be enabled to allow users to "request" access to a site.

This feature sends an email to the dedicated site owner, which contains a link to provide access.

The following article explains how to enable the feature:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2011/03/15/want-to-use-manage-access-requests-feature-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

You must have outgoing email configured for SharePoint to send the request emails.

As per the article, this feature may not be suitable for a large farm, where site owners are likely to change frequently.